# how to use Activity in sub class

Tags: android, android-intent

Conceptual problem here!
I want to break down a program into simpler more focused classes. The first one I am doing  requires a startActivityForResult() which in turn depends on an Activity.

I can pass the Activity to the class. But there is a problem in the caller when I use getActivity() this seems to be undefined for the class. 
Why isn't getActivity documented by the way?

Comment: can you post a code example what is not compiled or gets runtimeerror?

Comment: Is this a fragment you are trying to use?